# How to apply one-hot encoding to big files?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas, machine-learning

I have 3 Gb train file and 350 Mb test file, 6 Gb RAM. That files seem to be not too big to hold them in the memory, but  I can't even append them (memory error occurs).

My current aproach looks this way:

```
# reading files
      dtypes = {'Semana' : 'int32',
                          'Agencia_ID' :'int32',
                          'Canal_ID' : 'int32',
                          'Ruta_SAK' : 'int32',
                          'Cliente-ID' : 'int32',
                          'Producto_ID':'int32',
                          'Venta_hoy':'float32',
                          'Venta_uni_hoy': 'int32',
                          'Dev_uni_proxima':'int32',
                          'Dev_proxima':'float32',
                          'Demanda_uni_equil':'int32'}

train = pd.read_csv('train.csv', dtype  = dtypes, usecols=["Semana", "Agencia_ID", "Canal_ID", 'Ruta_SAK',  'Cliente_ID', 'Producto_ID','Demanda_uni_equil'])
test = pd.read_csv('test.csv',dtype  = dtypes)
ids = test['id']
test.drop(['id'], axis =1, inplace = True)

shapeTrain = train.shape[0]
shapeTest = test.shape[0]

train = train.append(test) # raises memory error

#applying one-hot encoding
train = pd.concat([train, pd.get_dummies(train['Semana'],sparse=True)], axis=1, join_axes=[train.index])
train.drop([11,'Semana'],axis=1, inplace = True)

train = pd.concat([train, pd.get_dummies(train['Producto_ID'],sparse=True)], axis=1, join_axes=[train.index])
train.drop([123,'Producto_ID'],axis=1, inplace = True)


train = pd.concat([train, pd.get_dummies(train['Canal_ID'],sparse=True)], axis=1, join_axes=[train.index])
train.drop([11,'Canal_ID'],axis=1, inplace = True)

# separating back to train and test
test = train[shapeTrain:shapeTrain+shapeTest]
train = train[0:shapeTrain]

test['id'] = ids

train.to_csv('train_1.csv', index=False)
test.to_csv('test_1.csv', index=False)
```

I see 2 ways to solve:

1) Somehow iterate through the files:

```
df_train = pd.read_csv('train.csv', chunksize=1500)
for chunk in df_train:
    #apply one-hot encoding
```

2) To decrease amount of columns by applying one-hot encoding only to train, and then to test, but for new categorical value setting all columns to 0.

3) Use [the hashing trick](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher.html)!

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Check out "hash trick". Thus, (1) you'll do not need to go over all the text twice and know all the words in advance (2) you'll have control over the number of bins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about specifying the data type when loading:

```
types = {'col1': np.dtype(type),
     'col2': np.dtype(type),
     'col3' : np.dtype(type),
     'col4': np.dtype(type),
     'col5': np.dtype(type) }

train = pd.read_csv('train.csv', dtype=types)
```

run `train.info()` if you are able to load it and check the memory usage.

Comment: So when does the error show up? While reading or while applying OHE?

Comment: Ok. How about giving Dask a try? It is a package developed by Continuum   Analytics which operates on dask dataframes which are composed of pandas dataframes. It uses all of your PC cores to work in parallel on dataframes stored either in RAM or in hard drive if larger than memory space: http://dask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dataframe-overview.html

Comment: never heard about, I'm going to try it

Answer (score 0):

Please try appending the datasets with ignore_index=True.

```
train.append(test, ignore_index=True)
```